# How can I create views on Mongodb Queries using mongo driver for Go?

Tags: mongodb, go

I am working with Golang and Mongodb. I am using https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2 mongo driver for Go. I want to write views on my queries but I found that there is no function defined for that. Mongo Views is a recent feature provided in version 3.4. I have checked it in other driver also:

https://godoc.org/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo

Its not even there. How can I get this feature in my driver ?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to write views on my queries but I found that there is no function defined for that.

Since MongoDB v3.4, there's a support for creating *read-only* views from existing collections or other views.

In order to create a view, you can execute [create()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/create/#dbcmd.create) database command. For example:

```
db.runCommand( { create: <view>, 
                 viewOn: <source>, 
                 pipeline: <pipeline>, 
                 collation: <collation> 
} );
```

For example if you have a `create` view command from mongo shell as below:

```
db.runCommand( {create:"testview", 
                viewOn: "collectionName", 
                pipeline: [ {"$project":{ "fieldA":1 } } ] 
});
```

Utilising [mongo-go-driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver) (currently version 0.0.9), the above create view command can be written in Go as below:

```
_, err = database.RunCommand(
    context.Background(),
    bson.NewDocument(bson.EC.String("create", "testview"),
                     bson.EC.String("viewOn", "collectionName"),
                     bson.EC.ArrayFromElements(
                         "pipeline", bson.VC.DocumentFromElements(
                             bson.EC.SubDocumentFromElements(
                                 "$project", bson.EC.Int32("fieldA", 1),),
                             ),
                         ),
                     ),
)
```